# suspend problem

Tags: suspend

I have tried a lot of distro on my machine, seems Eos only has this problem. why can't it wake up from suspend? tried googling it, didn't find any answer. the machine is a HP pavilion g4 laptop. graphics driver are installed. average linux user here.

Comment: Yep, same here. And I'm seeing a number of people with the same issue and no one seems to have a solution.